# Extracting image of current state from Vmware VM without snapshots

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a Vmware VM with a lot of snapshots that take a lot of space. I want to move VM to another disk, but only current state without snapshots because of space limitations. Is there any other way to do that than to copy whole VM with snapshots and then delete all the unnecessary ones then copy cleaned VM again to the desired location?

Comment: Actually it would be best if it would be possible to export current state or any snapshot state of VM without including all of snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

The better option is to create a "Full Clone" of that VM. In the snapshot manager, there should be the option to select the specific snapshot you wish to clone (including "Current State") and create a full clone of that VM. During the clone process you will be able to specify where the VM's files should be placed. The end result should not contain any of the snapshot information either.

More info: [Cloning VMs in Workstation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-5DE53D02-9A58-4F9F-84BE-FE21AE82EA4E.html)